# Grabbing a user_group in MODx

Tags: user-controls, content-management-system, authentication, modx

Currently I have a Client login area. In this login area I was going to create a snippet that shows certain information for 'Admin' users.

I had a feeling I could use

```
<?php
if ($modx->getLoginUserType()) {
   echo 'hi';
} else {}
?>
```

However, all User Types are web.

I was also looking around and found a script that prints out web-users of a web-group:
http://modxcms.com/forums/index.php/topic,43139.0.html

Any Advice?

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = $modx->isMemberOfWebGroup( array(
    'Editors'
));
if ($test === true) {
    // Is a member of the group
} else {
    // Is not a member of the group
}
```

see: http://wiki.modxcms.com/index.php/API:isMemberOfWebGroup